# How can I put an ad banner after a row of content using React and Tailwind CSS?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make news site using React and Tailwind. I've got two APIs: the first one contains all articles and second one contains all ads. I want make UI like this: [image: screenshot]

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import Cards from "../../components/GridCards";
import Circle from "../../components/svgs/Circle";

//this is statically generated page
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch("https://pranerbangla.com/api/vb1/category-tree");
  const data = await res.json();

  const content = data["data"];

  const paths = content.map((pageName) => {
    return {
      params: { id: pageName.id.toString() },
    };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false, // true or 'blocking'
  };
}

//getting items by ids also trying to fetch second api which contain ads
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const id = context.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://pranerbangla.com/api/vb1/category-to-post/" + id
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  const resAdd = await fetch("http://pranerbangla.com/api/vb1/advertisement"); //ads api
  const adData = await resAdd.json();

  const content = data["data"];
  const contentAd = adData["data"];

  return {
    props: {
      pages: content,
      advertise: contentAd,
    },
  };
}

function CategoryPage({ pages, advertise }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {advertise.map((ad) => {
        if (ad.add_space === "categoty") {
          return (
            <div className="mx-48">
              <img
                className="h-32 w-full object-fill"
                src={`https://pranerbangla.com/${ad.image}`}
                alt=""
                srcset=""
              />
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}

      <div className="flex justify-between mx-48 border-b-2 my-8 ">
        {[pages[0]].map((pageItem, i) => {
          return (
            <h1
              key={i}
              className="flex items-center text-base text-3xl text-black mb-4 dark:text-white"
            >
              <Circle className=" h-3 pr-2 mb-1" />
              {pageItem.category_name_bn}
            </h1>
          );
        })}

        <h1 className="flex items-center text-base text-lg text-black mb-4 dark:text-white">
          সাম্প্রতিক পোস্ট (206)
        </h1>
      </div>

      <div className="grid grid-cols-4 mb-4 gap-10 mx-48 ">
        {pages?.map((pageItem) => {
          return (
            <Cards
              title={pageItem.title_bn}
              category={pageItem.category_name_bn}
              time={pageItem.created_at}
              imgSrc={pageItem.image}
              route={pageItem.id}
              status={pageItem.status}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CategoryPage;
```

How can I achieve this layout, where after every 8 items there will be an ad banner? Mine has all of the ads displaying in one place. I know why this is happening, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should slice your articles array to each 8 items group.

```
const sliceArrayIntoGroups = (arr, size) => {
    var step = 0, sliceArr = [], len = arr.length;
    while (step < len) {
      sliceArr.push(arr.slice(step, step += size));
    }
    return sliceArr;
}

const groupArticle = sliceArrayIntoGroups(page, 8);
```

and you can add 1 ads to each group

```
const data = groupArticle.map((item, index) => ({
    articles: item,
    ad: advertise[index]
}))
```

So you can loop through the data array

```
data.map((group) => {
    return <div>
        <div className="flex flex-wrap">
            {group.articles.map(article => <Article/>)}
        </div>
        <div className='mx-48'>   
            <img className='h-32 w-full object-fill' src= {`https://pranerbangla.com/${group.ad.image}`} alt="" srcset="" />
        </div>
    </div>
})
```